# How to view Tomcat errors on netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

I'm writing server-side Java in NetBeans 8.1 EE. In Eclipse, which I'm used to, when Tomcat throws `The requested resource is not available`, there's a message in the console.  What's the NetBeans equivalent of that?

Comment: Check the $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out and copy paste here the log to find root cause

Answer (score 0):

When you run your web application in Netbeans multiple tabs open in the output window(normally at the bottom right). One called something like `YourWebApplication (run)` and another called `Apache Tomcat or Tom(EE)` and a third `Apache Tomcat or Tom(EE) Log`. I believe the output you are looking for should be in the third tab. One can also goto the `Services` window, select your tomcat server under `Servers`, and select View Server Log from the popup menu.